# Python method not running

Tags: python-2.7

I have a method `play_lottery()` that I am trying to run in my script.
The method is called at the base of the script but nothing appears to be executing.

I have put the `print 10` line in debugging and I cannot even see execution reaching this point.

Any ideas what is going on here?

This is `Python 2.7.10` running on OSX.

```
def play_lottery():
    print 10
    num = 0
    range = 150000000
    while num < range:
        yield
        print num
        num += 1


play_lottery()
```

Comment: Lets reduce it ti something that could work. Replace your call `play_lottery()` with `print 'something runs'`. If that prints we know more.

Comment: @jhinghaus if I do `print ok` on either side of the call to `play_lottery()` they both print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling your generator function creates a generator object. You never actually request anything from the generator though, so it isn't run.

You need to request values from the generator:

```
import itertools

lot_gen = play_lottery()

# Take the first 3
vals = list(itertools.islice(lot_gen, 3))
```

This will at least cause your generator to run.

And you don't need to use `islice` necessarily. You just need to request values from the generator by some means.

Comment: What should `itertools` be?

Answer (score 1):

What you have created is the python generator since yield keyword is used in side function. Generators in python are memory friendly. Generators won't execute unless you call **next** method on generator until *StopIteration*

Here you code looks fine. All you have to do is either of the following. First take the generator into variable

```
play_lottery_gen = play_lottery()
```

Now you can retrieve the next value using next method

```
play_lottery_gen.next()
```

Or, you can also built in method **next** to retrieve the next value

```
next(play_lottery_gen)
```

You can convert generator into the list by simply passing it into the **list** factory function. But it is memory inefficient

```
list(play_lottery_gen)
```